# VBA excel Reference Userform as variable to get data

Tags: excel, vba, variables, userform

I have a few days on this problem. i am using excel VBA to fill in a Word Doc.
I have multiple Userforms that contains textBoxes, ComboBoxes etc. in order to keep code small and not to create the same module over and over i need to change only the FormName

this code is working to fill in the Word Doc

```
wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("#MonthBox").Item(1).Range.Text = Request_Form_1.MonthBox.Value
```

but i want to use variable to reference the Userform in a module but i get all types of errors

```
Dim FormName As String
FormName = "Request_Form_1"
wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("#MonthBox").Item(1).Range.Text = FormName.MonthBox.Value
```

Kind regards

Thank you for your support
What i had tried and is not working

1. Tried UserForms(NumeForma)
   `MsgBox UserForms(NumeForma).LunaBox.Value` the form is visible but i get *error 13 type mismatch*
2. Tried to insert a module that include `ShowAnyForm()` call `MsgBox ShowAnyForm(NumeForma).LunaBox.Value` error "Expected Function or variable"
3. Change in module `ShowAnyForm()` from `Sub` to `Function` using `MsgBox ShowAnyForm(NumeForma).LunaBox.Value` error 424 object required

Comment: You searched for: "excel vba userform name as variable"?

Comment: yes i tried multiple methods and all of them without success, because i did not understand them. that is why i asked here. i searched for a few days now

Comment: You found the linkto `ShowAnyForm`? You should have mentioned that.

Comment: You saw my edit in answer. Problem found ;) Also`ShowAnyForm`isn't a function (returns nothing), it only makes a UserForm visible!

Comment: And don't change ListBox name (MonthBox/LunaBox). Use one or the other not both

Comment: Just recognized you want to refernece the userform in a module. Is that sub/function called by the userform (and you pass its name as string)? Then solution will be simpler (just pass Listbox reference instead of string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything just in front or after a dot (like `FormName.`) can't be (easy) replaced by a variable as it's an object or a member (but you can [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function) it!).

Variables have to be passed as argument to a parameter, but as many objects are accessible by a collection, that's the way we usually go.

**Loaded** userforms can be found in the [UserForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/userform-object) collection. But they can only be accessed by their item index (0 to `UserForms.Count() -1`), not their name. So you need sth. like:

```vb
'code by http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm
For Each Obj In VBA.UserForms
     If StrComp(FormName, Obj.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' If Obj.Name matches FormName loop is exited and Obj contains the UserForm reference of FormName.
         Exit For
     End If
Next Obj
```

to get an loaded userform reference.
Samplecode is availible at [Show Any Form](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm).

Your code should look like:

```vb
wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("#MonthBox").Item(1).Range.Text = ControlValueByName(FormName:=FormName, ControlName:="MonthBox", _
        ProcName:="Value", CallType:=vbGet)
```

I add a function to return UserForm reference for a given FormName:

```vb
'Code inspired by http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm
Public Function UserFormByName(ByVal FormName As String) As UserForm
Dim Obj As Variant
For Each Obj In VBA.UserForms
    If StrComp(FormName, Obj.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next Obj
If Obj Is Nothing Then ' UserForm not loaded
    Err.Clear
    Set Obj = VBA.UserForms.Add(FormName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error Calling Form: " & FormName
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
Set UserFormByName = Obj
End Function
```

Now you can use:

```vb
wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("#MonthBox").Item(1).Range.Text = UserFormByName(FormName).MonthBox.Value
```

Things get easier if you call a method from the userform, as you can simply pass the reference to it. See OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63329750/9439330)

On form:

```vb
Private Sub InregistreazaButtonActive2_Click()
    ToWord Me
End Sub
```

In module:

```vb
Sub ToWord(ByRef Caller As UserForm)
    MsgBox Caller.AnBox.Value
End Sub
```

Instead of the forms reference, you can pass the listbox reference, that contains the form reference too, as it is a child object the form, so form is `ListBox.Parent`.

```vb
Private Sub InregistreazaButtonActive2_Click()
    ToWord Me.AnBox
End Sub

Sub ToWord(ByRef CallerListBox As ListBox)
    MsgBox CallerListBox.Value
    Debug.Print CallerListBox.Parent.Name ' shows form name of listbox 
End Sub
```

By passing references you don't have to worry about multiple instances (that woud have same name) as each instance has its own reference.

Comment: There is no other easy way to reference the form? something like ```Controls("Check" & x)```

Comment: As I said the collection is `UserForms` (so `UserForms(FormName)` will do it if the form is loaded) , but only contains loaded forms. That's why you need `ShowAnyForm` from last link!

Comment: Please belive me, form is loaded / visible but on line ```MsgBox UserForms(NumeForma).LunaBox.Value```  i get run-tyme error' '13' Type mismatch

Comment: Can't test now, but try `ControlValueByName` function from the link to `ShowAnyForm`. It uses the mentioned CallByName function, as maybe Userforms don't return the objects refernce. I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: Just tested my code -> works with `ControlValueByName` ,b but fails with `UserForms(FormName)`, because unlike Ms Access forms collection, you can only get values by index, not by name. That's why  `ControlValueByName` use a for loop to get the index to the name of the form!

Answer (score 0):

First i want to say thank you @ComputerVersteher
Second  will paste the hole code

1. In excel worksheet i have a shape, on click will call the form

```
Sub Start_Cerere_De_Autentificare_1_Click()
    Cerere_De_Autentificare_2.Show False
End Sub
```

2. On form i have 3 textboxes (ZiBox, LunaBox, AnBox)

```
Public Sub UserForm_Activate()
     ZiBox = Day(Date)
     LunaBox = Month(Date)
     AnBox = Year(Date)
End Sub
Private Sub InregistreazaButtonActive2_Click()
    Call ToWord_CerereDeAutentificare2
End Sub
```

3. When register button is pressed it will call

```
Sub ToWord_CerereDeAutentificare2()

    Dim NumeForma As String
    NumeForma = "Cerere_De_Autentificare_2"

    Dim AllName As Object
    Set AllName = UserFormByName(NumeForma)

    MsgBox AllName.AnBox.Value
End Sub
```

4. This will call your code who will return the form name and in the end the value stored in the Textboxes can be easily accessed with one line **MsgBox AllName.AnBox.Value**

```
Public Function UserFormByName(FormName As String) As UserForm
Dim Obj As Variant
For Each Obj In VBA.UserForms
    If StrComp(FormName, Obj.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next Obj
If Obj Is Nothing Then ' UserForm not loaded
    Err.Clear
    Set Obj = VBA.UserForms.Add(FormName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error Calling Form: " & FormName
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
Set UserFormByName = Obj
End Function
```

Thank you again

Comment: As I assumed, the form calls the sub, but I don't get the point why you use form name to get listbox value and not `Cerere_De_Autentificare_2`. If that is only a simplyfied example and `ToWord_CerereDeAutentificare2`is used by more forms, how do you know what form is calling. To only get  acces  to the listbox, you could pass its reference as argument to a parameter in `ToWord_CerereDeAutentificare2`. That would be easier than getting form reference by its name (btw `UserFormByName` can't be used for more than one instance of a form!).

Comment: I wanted to do like this, because i will need to create a 50 forms and 50 `ToWord_` modules and 50 Word templates. The last revision of the forms and word templates are stored in an excel sheet (for traceability), in order to make a change easy i search the form name in excel sheet and use it in the VBA code. Regarding `UserFormByName` i will dig more into this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are aware that you can manipulate forms by code (e.g. create, edit, delete controls) at run-time? Also you can open multiple independent instance of one UserForm at same time. Combined with passing object refences to methds, that may enable you to use ine form for all. I will extend my answer to show you how to one `ToWord` that shows value for any listbox on any form.

Comment: Please show me a small small example not to take allot of your time, i will make my researches after.